# Rails global state variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, global

I need to keep some kind of state in my Rails project.
Some kind of global variable or something like that, which has an initial value at the server startup, and could be accessed and modified everywhere in the project. How to do that? What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file in `config/initializers` folder and create your global variable there.

```
# config/initializers/my_var.rb
$my_global_var = 'hello'
```

But usually there are "cleaner" ways to do this. Global variables are not thread-safe and this is kinda hot topic these days.

Comment: Agree with Sergio, if possible look for alternate solution. Later in the project it will cause issue which are difficult to debug

Comment: Yeah, I've tryied. And the variables values are not correct in some processes, because the not thread-safeness.
So, what can I do? Create a model to store only a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution here could be [settingslogic gem](https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic) . You define settings in yaml file and then you can access them anywhere in the code. Read and set them. At the same it enables you to have more than just one 'global variable'. In most of the projects I've worked with, settings weren't changed during the runtime, but if you need that behaviour, you can just do it.

```
# config/application.yml
defaults: &defaults
  my_global_variable: 100

development:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults

#And then anywhere in the application you can do:
Settings['my_global_variable'] = 200
```

Comment: It works, the problem is that as somebody say above, it's not thread-safe.